# The file gives an error when I add label position to python pptx doughnut chart

Tags: python, python-pptx

I try to add labels for a doughnut chart. Everything works fine until I try to set the position of labels. Neither `BEST_FIT` nor `OUTSIDE_END` work. When I add `data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.BEST_FIT` line the file just won't open. Here is the code:

```
from pptx import Presentation
from pptx.chart.data import ChartData
from pptx.enum.chart import XL_CHART_TYPE, XL_LABEL_POSITION
from pptx.util import Inches, Pt


prs = Presentation()
slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[6])  # blank slide

chart_data = ChartData()
chart_data.categories = ['aaa','bbb', 'ccc','ddd', 'eee', 'fff','ggg','hhh', 'iii', 'jjj','kkk','lll','mmm', 'nnn']
chart_data.add_series('Test', [10,50,60,30,5,35,10,15,70,1,10,5,60,30])   

x, y, cx, cy = Inches(1), Inches(1), Inches(8), Inches(6)
chart = slide.shapes.add_chart(XL_CHART_TYPE.DOUGHNUT, x, y, cx, cy, chart_data).chart


chart.plots[0].has_data_labels=True
data_labels = chart.plots[0].data_labels
data_labels.font.size = Pt(12)
data_labels.show_percentage = True
data_labels.show_category_name = True
data_labels.show_value = True
data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.BEST_FIT
#or
#data_labels.position = XL_LABEL_POSITION.OUTSIDE_END


prs.save('test.pptx')
```

As you can imagine, my real data category names are much longer and without proper positioning it is impossible to read. So how can I set the position of labels so that they are readable?

Comment: Try setting the data labels on the first series rather than the plot: `data_labels = chart.plots[0].series[0].data_labels`

Comment: This doesn't work, too.